# Synonyms for wondering hard

Tags: expressions, idioms, synonyms

Can someone help me to identify some English synonyms/idioms meaning to "wonder so hard"? The word or phrase I'm looking for could be used in a situation where somebody tries to solve a very confusing riddle or is unable to manage what is going on.

I thought one example might be "breaking [somebody's] head open" (like in other languages: "den Kopf zerbrechen" or "rompersi la testa"), but I realized that the English meaning is literal in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some ideas for you.

I had to really scratch my head about that one.

I was completely lost in that lecture.  For the life of me, I could not figure out what the heck the professor was talking about.

I had to wrack my brain to solve that riddle.

Answer (score 2):

A word like *ponder* or *ruminate* would be synonyms, but neither has the intensity I think you're looking for.  There's an idiom, "crack one's brains," or "rack one's brains," that might work.  I personally use a phrase that involves smoke coming out of my ears.

P.S.  "Wrack one's brains" is often used; according to [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/rack-wrack/) *rack* is correct.

Comment: +1 for the (w)rack one's brains! According to [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rack) both are correct when used figuratively.

Answer (score 1):

I've *ruminated* over the problem for months.

The problem is *driving me crazy*.

The problem is *puzzling* me.

I'm *cogitating* about the problem.

I'm still *mulling* over it.

Answer (score 0):

**Mind-blowing**

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mind-blowing): overwhelming; astounding: *Spending a week in the jungle was a mind-blowing experience.*

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/mind-blowing): surprising, shocking, and often difficult to understand or imagine: *The movie’s special effects are mind-blowing.*

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mind-blowing): Overwhelmingly impressive: *For a kid, Chicago was really mind-blowing.*

**Mind-boggling**

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mind-boggling): intellectually overwhelming: *a mind-boggling puzzle*

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/mind-boggling): very large, unusual, or complicated and not easy to imagine: *athletes who earn a mind-boggling amount of money*

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/mind-boggling): extremely surprising and difficult to understand or imagine: *She was paid the mind-boggling sum of ten million dollars for that film.*