# More words to describe the action of thinking

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, descriptive-grammar, creative-writing

My character is in the beginning stages of a life-or-death situation and he knows it. "Racking his brain for possible solutions" feels played out. But words like ruminating, fretting, musing, etc don't sound *frantic* enough. Does anyone have any ideas on how they would right it? The more synonyms the better.

Comment: What's wrong with the words you already know? Knowing that will help us zero in on the _mot juste._ What about " flustered", "discombobulated", "funky", etc.?

Comment: I decided to just go with "frantically vacillated between possible solutions." I still don't really like it.... I think it could be more descriptive/vivid. I don't really want a synonym, I moreso want ideas on how to better illustrate his desperation and racing thoughts.

Comment: "He frantically vacillated" or "he was frantically vacillating".

Comment: How about _As he was caught up in the liminal space between life and death, his mind kept frantically racing between possible alternatives.?_

Comment: Show don't tell? To illustrate desperation and racing thoughts, describe what we'd see. Was he relaxed or shaking? Whistling with joy or frenzy? Meditating or sweating? Once you show us, the narrative no longer needs to tell us.

Comment: *Panic* suggests frantic, as do lots of other obvious possibilities. I'm guessing that you don't actually mean blind panic, but want something that simultaneously suggests panic and genius-level thought processes (this being your resourceful hero). So good luck with that.

Comment: Closely related: [synonyms for wondering hard](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262193/synonyms-for-wondering-hard).